# Frequency Processing

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, signal-processing, 8051

I am truly lost. I need some help and a redirection. I am trying to make a chromatic tuner using AT89C2051. My project would only be from C1 until B5.

The signal would be from a cable or stereo jack.

I will be using the ADC0848 for the conversion.

I've been reading up on how frequency works but I can't seem to understand a lot of things. If my ADC and MCU are only 8-bits. How would I determine the frequency of the input in the code or inside the MCU?

I'm sorry if this is a very dumb question. I'm not an engineering student or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an Analog to Digital Converter gives you an *instantaneous* reading of the voltage (well, it takes time for it to do its thing...) It gives you  a reading now, now, now, now, now, etc. And you could get readings like `-200`, `-100`, `-20`, `+50`, `+75`, `+60`, `+10`, `-40`.

Frequency is time dependent. If you got the above readings, you could interpret that the maximum voltage was around `+75` (whatever the units are), and that the wave crossed the `0` mark between the third and fourth reading, going upwards, and the seventh and eighth readings, going downwards. If you wanted to know what the frequency was, you'd need to know what time those crossings happened. From that you could work out the frequency of the wave. Don't forget that you should calculate the difference in times between two upward or two downward crossings!

On the piano, `C1` is 32.703 Hz. `B5` is 987.77 Hz. That's not too bad - if you sampled the wave 4,000 times a second (minimum! See "Nyquist rate" if you want the maths) you could do those sorts of zero-crossing calculations to get a reasonable frequency count. However, more samples per second is always better!

But personally I'd use the AT89C2051's inbuilt analog comparator. `P1.0` and `P1.1` can be set to continually compare two analog voltages. When `P1.0` > `P1.1` then `P3.6` is a `1`. Otherwise it's a `0`. By:

1. Ensuring the sampled waveform on `P1.0` is offset to `VCC/2`, and doesn't clip at either `VCC` or `GND`;
2. Using a 50/50 voltage divider on `P1.1`;
3. Asking the MCU to interrupt when `P3.6` changes;

then you can get the zero-crossing detection for "free". You can then read the timer at each interrupt and do the calculations to get the frequency.

Of course that requires the hardware to be wired correctly, and the Timer to be set up correctly, and the Analog Comparator to be set up correctly, and the interrupt to be set up correctly... and then you can calculate and display the frequency! Or even better, convert that frequency to a note value using a lookup table.

Comment: Interesting counterweight to my answer. I guess it will depend on the temperament of the OP which he finds easier to take forward.

Comment: I want to pursue your solution using the Analog Comparator because it will save me from using ADC if I understand correctly? My understanding is that I should utilize a timer at the start of the loop and when interrupt happens the time should be recorded. Then, t2 - t1 and then I can use the f = 1/t formula? Is it also required to get a lot of interrupts like what you said about Nyquist rate or getting two points is enough?

Comment: @WarrenGojar If you use the in-built analog comparator then you won't need an external ADC - but you will need external hardware to "shift" the analog signal from (I presume) +/-1V to 0-5V before giving it to P0.0. You'll also need a 50:50 voltage divider on P0.1 as the reference. Then, after you've initialised as I described, you'll get an interrupt every time the pin changes state. You'll want to only pay attention to the 0-to-1 transitions (or 1-to-0) for full-duty cycles. Every time you get an interrupt, record the new time, then subtract the old time - and yes, `f=1/t`

Comment: Then, you're not the one doing the sampling: the hardware is. So Nyquist rate is not a factor.

Comment: To "shift" the analog signal can I use an op-amp and probably utilize low-pass filters before the op-amp? Thanks for the awesome answer. This is much more feasible for me because of certain limitations.

Comment: I'm not sure on how noisy your signal is going to be - you don't mention your pickup method. A filter may be problematic. To shift the signal it may just be as simple as feeding the signal into a 0.1uF capacitor, then into a 50:50 voltage divider to add a DC bias. You will definitely want to balance all four resistors in the dividers!

Comment: I am using a stereo jack for the signal and a typical pickup from an electric guitar or other electric instruments. 

Here is the circuit design I am using with using an op-amp and the voltage divider before the P1.1: http://imgur.com/a/y3Egj

I only copied the op-amp design from an Arduino project so if there are mistakes in the resistor or capacitor values feel free to correct me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Calm down.

First, use an MCU that has a well established C library available for it, then you need not worry about the limitations of '8 bits'. From a quick look, it appears that C is available for the 8051 you have chosen.

Then read up on pitch estimation, this is the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm) on it.

It's usually a lot easier to develop your pitch detection algorithm on your PC, either in C, or a higher level language like python or Matlab, before porting it to the MCU.

Don't worry initially about using an algorithm that's small enough to port to the small address space of the AT89, just get something working. It's far easier to modify an existing working program, than to write one from scratch in a target size. It's far easier to compare a new approach with a working one than to try to debug it by itself.

Start small with the MCU as well. Just capture some samples, then send them to the PC for processing.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D I've read up on the stuff and someone else also recommended me the FFT. But I think I am not ready for that kind of algorithms since we didn't have complex maths in our curriculum. Although, your suggestion has given me light and a method.